# how to check mysql connexion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would want to check if there is a connection with the database before execute the query .

But when I write `if mysql_connection ...` then it passes twice on `mysql_connection`:

```
def mysql_connection
  puts "mysql_connection 1"

  read_config_file
  @connexion = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => @conf['host'], :username => @conf['user'], :password => @conf['password'], :database=> @conf['base'], :port => @conf['port'])
end 

# USER QUERY MYSQL
def mysql_select_user(value)
  puts "select"

  # if mysql_connection then
    p = mysql_connection.query("select #{value} from User")   
    p.each do |f| 
      puts "value : #{f}" 
      mysql_close
    end 
  # else
  # end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mysql2::Client#ping` method (from docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Client#ping-instance_method)